# clone issue with git-tf and TFS-2010

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I'm trying to clone a team project from TFS 2010 using git-tf, but I'm getting the following error:

```
PS C:\git> git-tf clone --deep http://path-to-tpc $/Test/Trunk test-2010
Connecting to TFS...
Cloning $/Test/Trunk into C:\git\test-2010: 0%
git-tf: The SOAP endpoint http://path-to-tpc/VersionControl/v4.0/repository.asmx could not be contacted.  HTTP status: 404
```

The v4.0/repository.asmx doesn't exist. "v3.0" does exist, so I tried renaming "v3.0" to "v4.0", but it looks like the service contract is different so I get other errors.

FYI., I don't have the same issues when cloning from TFS 2015.

How can I deep clone a TFS 2010 team project to a local git repo? 
Is this a git-tf version issue - I'm using v2.0.3.20131219.
I noticed there is a --version option when using git-tf clone, but the documentation is very limited.

Any help/recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to resolve my own issue. I'll post the resolution as it might hopefully save some other people some headaches.

I connect to both TFS 2010 and TFS 2015. This is a temporary thing as we're moving everything to TFS 2015. When I switch between team projects (in Visual Studio) hosted in TFS 2010 and TFS 2015, I need to delete my TFS cache. Trying to clone repositories using git-tf is no different, that is, I needed to clear my TFS cache i.e.

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache
```

Once I clear the TFS cache, everything works.